# File upload using Guava and apache common?

Tags: guava, apache-commons

I use guava and apache commons to convert temporary image that have been loaded from the server but the conversion result is a corrupted file. the problem that "sampleFile" is corrupted and I don't know why until I have no error.

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;


public class imageDecoder {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] data = null;
        final File input = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\multipartBody2180016028702918119asTemporaryFile");
        try {
            data = Base64.decodeBase64(Files.toByteArray(input));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print("problem");
        }
        final File f = new File(String.format("sampleFile_%s.jpg", UUID.randomUUID()));

        try {
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();
            final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really not possible to help you unless you can provide more information on what exactly the problem is. That you're getting a corrupted file really doesn't tell us much.

Comment: the problem that when I open the temporary file "multipartBody2180016028702918119asTemporaryFile" that I have uploaded from the client side in paint or any image editor I got the right image. But after conversion with this class I got a corrupted JPEG file that I couldn't open with any of my edits images

Comment: So you are able to open the temporary file as an image, but not the sample sample file? That's one thing that would definitely be helpful to mention in the question.

Comment: yes, this is exactly my problem, sorry, it's my first time :)

Comment: FYI you don't need to use backslash as directory separators. Java converts `/` to `\ ` on Windows. `new File("C:/foo/bar")` works just fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like the the original file (`input`) contains the actual bytes of the image. But for some reason, you're then reading those bytes in as if they are the Base 64 encoded ASCII representation of the image. Clearly they aren't, so why are you doing this? If you skip the `Base64.decodeBase64` step, I'm guessing things will work as expected.

Of course, in that case what you're doing is simply copying the bytes of `input` to `f`, which is simpler and more efficient to do as:

```
Files.copy(input, f);
```

Or if you have no need to leave the temporary file where it is, moving the file is even better:

```
Files.move(input, f);
```